# Gradle executing curl doesn't upload files

Tags: android, curl, jenkins, gradle

I have a Gradle task `publish` to upload my application using `curl`:

```
task publish(dependsOn: assembleRelease) << {
    def apkName = group + "-" + revision + "-" + android.defaultConfig.versionName + "-release";
    println "Publishing $project.buildDir/apk/" + apkName + ".apk to mobileappstore.com";
    exec {
        executable "/bin/sh"
        args "-c", "curl -k -u 'CD:w2'" +
                " -F upload=@$project.buildDir/apk/" + apkName +
                ".apk -F tags=" + apkName + " http://mobileappstore.com/AE/Build/Upload";
    }
}
```

However, there is an error. The output is:

```
Publishing [...]/main/build/apk/null-1.0-release.apk to mobileappstore.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (26) failed creating formpost data
:main:publish FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '[...]/main/build.gradle' line: 103

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':main:publish'.
> Process 'command '/bin/sh'' finished with non-zero exit value 26
```

Another approach I tried:

```
task publish(dependsOn: assembleRelease) << {
    def apkName = android.defaultConfig.versionName + "-release";
    println "Publishing $project.buildDir/apk/" + apkName + ".apk to mobileappstore.com";
    exec {
        executable "/bin/sh"
        args "-c", "curl -k -u ", "-F upload=@$project.buildDir/apk/Ae-0.0.1-test.apk", "-F tags=AutoBuild" "https://mobileappstore.com/AE/Build/Upload";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':main:publish'.
> No such property: https://mobileapptore.com/AE/Build/Upload for class:       org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction_Decorated
```

Answer (score 1):

The `args` line is missing a comma before the URL. Also, each argument needs to be passed separately (typically that's anywhere you put a space on the command line). Also, why don't you execute `curl` directly?

Comment: how can i execute curl directly in gradle? or you mean to execute as separate step in Jenkins?

Comment: I mean `executable "curl"` rather than `executable "/bin/sh"`.

Comment: Each argument needs to be passed separately (typically that's anywhere you put a space on the command line).

Comment: `executable "curl"; args "-k", "-u", ...`

Comment: exec{
        executable "curl"; args "-k", "-u", "'CI.:1'", "-F upload=@$project.buildDir/apk/", "$apkName"," http://mobileapp.com/AERL-MOBL/Build/Upload"
    }
}
now like this

Comment: if i using curl manually it's curl: (1) Protocol  http not supported or disabled in libcurl